# csv not formated correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have problems with the correct formating of the csv, when i create a df I get the df in this format

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,encoding='iso-8859-15')
```

```
    Value
    99;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS4.2) bei Anfang Boxen...
1   100;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS4.2) bei Anfang Boxe...
2   102;3;;Sicherheitslichtgitter (0BSTR4.1) bei E...
3   145;3;;Sicherheitstür (0SS3b.5) bei Einspeisef..
```

when i open it in excel i got the correct column seperation

has this something to do with the `delimiter`?

Comment: You should use `sep=';'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the delimiter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,encoding='iso-8859-15', sep=';')
```